# how to manipulate elements of a tensor if you have a set of indices? (torch.topk())

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

suppose i have a tensor and using torch.topk function i get the max k elements of a tensor and their indices. like the following code

```
>>> x = torch.arange(1., 6.)
>>> x
tensor([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.])
>>> torch.topk(x, 3)
torch.return_types.topk(values=tensor([5., 4., 3.]), indices=tensor([4, 3, 2]))
```

now suppose i want to set the above max k elements to 0 but keep them in the same position in original tensor. How can i do that?

if k was =3 then the new tensor should look like:

tensor([ 1.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.])

basically, How can i use the indeces of these max k elements (return of the topk() torch function) to zero(set their values to 0) the original values in these positions out?

preferred would be a suggestion of a torch method that does what im asking. if not it would be best for the solution to be as efficient as possible.

Thank you for the help in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The [`torch.topk`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.topk.html) function returns the indices of the top-k elements on the provided dimension. You can perform the reassignment operation using [`torch.scatter`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.scatter.html):

```
>>> _, i = x.topk(k=3)
>>> x.scatter(dim=0, index=i, value=0)
tensor([1., 2., 0., 0., 0.])
```

Comment: im getting RuntimeError: selected index k out of range. do you have solution for this?

Comment: how can this be applied to a 2-d tensor?

Comment: Please update your question with a 2d tensor if that is what you are looking for.